# How to postEvent() in LWJGL application

Tags: java, automation, lwjgl, keyboard-events

Is it possible to post a `KeyEvent` to an LWJGL window? I'd like to programmatically send key presses and key releases. I have multiple windows in my application, so I cant use `java.awt.Robot` because it requires focus.

I've tried so far

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(
    new KeyEvent(null, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0,
    KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, '\0')
);
```

without success. I only get

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
```

because of the null parameter. I've also tried to put an anonymous `java.awt.Component` like `new JPanel()` instead of null but nothing happend. What is the correct way to achieve what I'd like to?

Comment: Why would you want to Lwjgl already has its own key events. Like `Keyboard.KEY_A` and lwjgl has enough functions to check wether a key is down, held or pressed. Just use a boolean that is true when the key is not down, then you have your release function (;

Comment: You didn't understand what I want to. I want to programmatically simualte keyboard events to LWJGL without to use `java.awt.Robot`. I don't want to poll an event but create one by myself and fire it to LWJGL

Comment: Why is it that you don't want to use robot?

Comment: I have multiple windows in my application, which I want parallelly to send events to. so I cant use java.awt.Robot because it only sends events to the window which currently has focus

Comment: Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html

Comment: That's not really helpful but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This what I said check out [Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html).

```
//Component for key focus, could focus it on anything really.
Component source = Component.getFocusComponent();

//Send dispatchEvent EventKey with your example key.
source.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(source, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0,
KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, '\0');
```

Ofcourse this needs some work, but I believe this is what you need.
If not then I totally don't know what you want sorry.